# How do you open InfoBoxes from outside links in Bing Map v7?

Tags: dictionary, bing

I have the following Bing Map v7: http://new.piperrealtycompany.com/temp/test2.cfm?city=fenton

In which I have a set of pushpins, with InfoBoxes associated with each one.

I'd have a list of corresponding links that are outside if the map.

I need the links in the list to open the corresponding InfoBoxes in the map and rolling over pushpins to highlight the corresponding link in list.

I'm trying to achieve something like this!  http://www.zillow.com/flint-township-mi/
.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

This is fairly easy to do. First you need to add a unique value to each pushpin as you add it to the map. For example:

```
var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter());
pin.MyPinID = 1234;
map.entities.push(pin);
```

Since you are using JavaScript it is easy to add custom properties to classes. If you specify a unique value for each pushpin you can then later loop through all the shapes on the map and look for this value. You can then take this value and link it to your list item. You can do this in a couple of different ways. One method is to specify it in the rel tag of the item. Another method is to pass the value into the item's click event like so:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="FindPushpin(1234);">Link to pushpin</a>
```

You can then create a method that loops through the shapes like so:

```
function FindPushpin(id){
    var cnt = map.entities.getLength();
    var pin, temp;

    for(var I = 0; I< cnt; I++){
      temp = map.entities.get(I);
      if(temp.MyPinID && temp.MyPinID == id){
         pin = temp;
         break;
      }
    }

    if(pin){
      //you found the relative pin
    }
}
```